# Air Mouse / Gyro Mouse Keyboard - Air mice Unable to Wake computer from Sleep - Win 7 / Win 10.

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, keyboard, sleep

I am using a Windows 7 PC as my streaming device, Over all its performing well, Just have an annoying problem as i have this pc tugged behind the TV, I have a cheap microsoft USB wireless keyboard and mouse that I use to control it. Recently I bought a couple of air-mice / gyro KB / Mouse combo device to replace them. Every air-mouse of the two that I have bought has worked fine as a controller except in one regard; they will not wake the computer from sleep (both s3 and s1 power states).

When I connect an air-mouse to any other computer I have access to it is also unable to wake that computer. The computers all have different hardware and run both windows and linux and are not affected in any other way. When I connect my wireless keyboard and mouse to any of these computers they are able to wake it up fine. The air-mice and the wireless keyboard and mouse superficially seem to use similar USB receivers. Both MS wireless kb mouse registers as HID so do the Air mouse / gyro kb mouse combo device.

I am at loss as to why these very similar bits of hardware should differ on this one function. Is there a reason for this? Is there any simple thing I am overlooking to get an air-mouse to wake a computer?

When i put the computer to sleep - I am able to wake the machine from sleep by hitting (any) key on the Keyboard (USB Keyboard Microsoft or Wireless* USB keyboard ASUS*)

I have tried 3 different branded Air mouse / keyboard combo devices like (please see links attached) When i put the same pc to sleep. i cannot wake the machine up by pressing either the mouse buttons or the keypad (keyboard buttons.. tried almost all key combinations)

Both the Asus wireless keyboard and These chine Air Mouse / KB combo devices both register under windows as HID - And under power management, i have enabled "Allow this device to wake the computer checked" But this setting has no effect on the air mouse's ability to wake the pc from sleep.

Here are the two Air mouse / wireless keyboard that i have tried

VIBOTON i8 Plus Backlight 2.4G Wireless Keyboard Air Mouse Multi-touch Pad XBOX 360 PS4 TV Box Android TV Pad PC Link: https://www.geekbuying.com/item/VIBOTON-i8-Plus-Wireless-backlight-keyboard-black-380853.html

H1 Full Touchpad Keyboard 6-Axis Gyro 2.4GHz Air Mouse with Backlight for Andriod/Windows/Mac OS/Linux Systems - Black

Link: https://www.geekbuying.com/item/H1-2-4Ghz-Backlight-Air-Mouse-Wireless-Touch-Keyboard-Black-386327.html

Can someone please assit with getting these Air Mouse / KBs to enable waking up the pc from sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Power Settings and Device Manager Settings and ensure you don't have the USB ports themselves being powered down during sleep modes. Yes, there is a setting to allow the computer to power down ports even if the device connected to it is set to wake the computer. If the port the Bluetooth Adapter is plugged into has no power, the wireless mouse/kb can't work.